# Swing JLabel text change on the running application

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a Swing window which contains a button a text box and a `JLabel` named as flag. According to the input after I click the button, the label should change from flag to some value.

How to achieve this in the same window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField field;
    public Test()
    {
        super("The title");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 90));
        ((JPanel) getContentPane()).setBorder(new EmptyBorder(13, 13, 13, 13) );
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton btn = new JButton("Change");
        btn.setActionCommand("myButton");
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        label = new JLabel("flag");
        field = new JTextField(5);
        add(field);
        add(btn);
        add(label);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("myButton"))
        {
            label.setText(field.getText());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: From another class can you create an object of `Test` as `Test t = new Test(); t.getLabel().setText("Change label text");`. I have created getters-setters to the label (getLabel()) ??

Answer (score 11):

Use `setText(str)` method of `JLabel` to dynamically change text displayed. In actionPerform of button write this:

```
jLabel.setText("new Value");
```

---

A simple demo code will be:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(250,100);

    final JLabel label = new JLabel("flag");
    JButton button = new JButton("Change flag");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            label.setText("new value");
        }
    });

    frame.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```