# How to add JLabel at run time in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, layout-manager

I am making am window application on Java.
I want to add label name at run time in my Swing application. How can I do this using Java Swing?

```
public class Component1 extends JPanel {

   Component1() {
      JLabel label = new JLabel("dd");
      label.setBounds(370, 340, 150, 20);
     // label.setText("labeVVl");
      add(label);
}

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    // create frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    // set frame attributes
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setTitle("My Frame");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Component1 Com = new Component1();
    Component add = frame.add(Com);
}
}
```

Comment: You don't want to add a `JLabel` at runtime, you want to change the text of a `JLabel`. Doing both is similar and there's plenty of already existing [ques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578205/swing-jlabel-text-change-on-the-running-application) [tions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279435/java-how-would-i-dynamically-add-swing-component-to-gui-on-click) dealing with this.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for tips.  The labels on the lower left are added dynamically.

Comment: 1) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: As an aside.  A `JLabel` will be invisible until text is added.  You might add the label at start-up, then set text to it during run-time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. this code should be works by add `revalidate()` and `repaint()` as notifiers for `LayoutManager`
2. don't to use [`NullLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/problems.html), use default [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) implemented for  [`JPanel` in AP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)I do that the same way
3. see [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
4. [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989230/714968)